# Stop Resharper from changing "from" to "@from"

Tags: c#, resharper

I have many methods that have a parameter called `from`. If I do some refactoring to such a method, R# decides to change the `from` to `@from`. But both the compiler and I are happy with `from` and we don't want this change. I can't find any way to suppress it.

Example method:

```
    public class ObjectA
    {
        public int J { get; set; }
        public int K { get; set; }
    }

    public class ObjectB
    {
        public int Y { get; set; }
        public int Z { get; set; }
    }

    public static ObjectB ConvertAtoB(ObjectA from)
    {
        return from != null
            ? new ObjectB
            {
                Y = from.J,
                Z = from.K,
            }
            : null;
    }
```

After invert condition twice on the if statement, the method looks like this:

```
    public static ObjectB ConvertAtoB(ObjectA from)
    {
        return @from != null
            ? new ObjectB
            {
                Y = @from.J,
                Z = @from.K,
            }
            : null;
    }
```

Is there any R# setting that will prevent this?

Comment: Why do you want a variable name to be the same as a contextual keyword? This causes ambiguity, and IMHO R# does the right thing here. I would chose a different variable name in the first place.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a parameter called `from`, otherwise it wouldn't compile. If I called the parameter `is` for example, then it wouldn't compile. But `from` is fine.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a parameter called @from either.

Comment: The fact that the compiler accepts it, doesn't mean it's a good idea. Otherwise there wouldn't be any buggy programs in the world ;-).

Comment: I'm with chris here. Why not just rename the parameter to `source` or something?

Comment: The point is this seems to be a Resharper functionality that I would like to suppress and I can't find a way of doing so. Whether I want to do this or not is beside the point because my naming convention creates perfectly compilable code. Please let me know if there is a way to disable this behaviour.

Comment: @demoncodemonkey see also [a similar problem I reported](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-275970), where variables with the same name as contextual keywords sometimes get unnecessary `@`s. Create a minimal example and report it on youtrack - stuff *does* get fixed.

Comment: @AakashM: good plan, I reported it here. http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-421482 Cheers!